# How to debug ssh2_sftp_rename?

Tags: php, rename, sftp

I'm having trouble with ssh2_sftp_rename, or in general with the SSH2/SFTP wrapper.

We have two SFTP servers.  One is a test server, which we've setup by ourself, and one is from a service provider.  On the test server, everything works fine while on the provided SFTP we cannot rename a file via PHP.  Manual renaming via sftp cli works fine.  Our SFTP server uses the protocol version 2.0 and remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, while the other one uses protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3.  So I'd guess they should act the same.

Here's the smallest code snippet for testing, which doesn't work:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('sftp.serviceprovider.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
$result = ssh2_sftp_rename($sftp, '/new/foo.xml.gz', '/processed/foo.xml.gz');

var_dump($result);
var_dump(error_get_last());
```

`$result` is `false` and `error_get_last()` returns `NULL`.  I also tried leaving the beginning slashes or any other combination I can think of, but it just "didn't work": the file is still in the 'new' folder.

So, unfortunately I cannot take a look into the log files of the service provider but I have requested an log excerpt or at least an analysis.  But I don't want to wait for their support center to answer my question and try to debug this stuff.

Is there any possibility to debug what `ssh2_sftp_rename` or `rename`are doing behind the scenes?  Does anyone else experienced something like this and found a solution?

Thanks for any hints,
  Matthias

Answer (score 1):

Diagnosing issues with libssh2 is nigh impossible. My recommendation: use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/intro.html). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$sftp->rename('filename.remote', 'newname.remote');

echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();
?>
```

In lieu of seeing the logs my guess would be a permissions issue but the logs should tell us for sure.